# Why type errors are not caught by IF Statement parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that comparison operators do not consider empty strings or non-integers to be errors?

Example:

```
        var x = “”;

        if (x>=1 && x<=10){
            console.log(x);     //validation code: error is expected to be thrown as variable x is not an integer
        } else {
            console.log(“Error: ” + x);
        }
```

Coding language: JavaScript (vanilla) 
Skill level: Beginner 
Editor: Visual Studio Code 
OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures): "JavaScript is a loosely typed and dynamic language. Variables in JavaScript are not directly associated with any particular value type, and any variable can be assigned (and re-assigned) values of all types"

In the case of comparisons, this has a [side-effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators): "In most cases, if the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript attempts to convert them to an appropriate type for the comparison."

When comparing a string to a number, Javascript will try to convert that string into a number value for the comparison. Empty strings are considered to have the number value `0`.

If you separate your if-statement into two separate comparisons, you'll see that:

`x >= 1` is `false` (because `0` is less than `1`)
`x <= 10` is `true` (because `0` is less than or equal to `10`)

This implicit type casting is the reason you won't get a type error. But since both conditions of your if-statement cannot be `true` at the same time for an empty string, you will get the error you log from the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, x value similar to NULL and comparison operators do not consider the condition  x >=1 && x<=10 as compare with NULL. Again, it's just my opinion.

```
var x = “”; // x is similar to NULL here 

    if (x>=1 && x<=10){
        console.log(x);     //validation code: error is expected to be thrown as variable x is not an integer
    } else {
        console.log(“Error: ” + x);
    } here
```